# Pandas groupby within a date range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider this sample data created by this code:

```
import random
np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-09-19', periods=1000, freq='D')
randomlist = np.random.choice(1000, 10000, replace=True)
print(f'randomlist length is {len(randomlist)}')
test = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': randomlist[:(len(rng))], 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })
```

The desired output is a groupby id, summing all values, but only within a particular date range of the Date column.  Even more complicated than that, I want to see the total Val by id for dates that are the following:

Using the date which is one month later than the earliest date for each id and one year later than that starting date of one month later than the earliest date.

So, for example, if my data appeared this way:

```
    id  Date        Val
0   684 2017-09-19  0.640472
1   684 2017-10-20  -0.732568
2   501 2017-08-21  -1.141365
3   501 2017-09-22  -0.283020
4   501 2017-09-23  0.725941
5   684 2017-09-24  0.56789
```

I would want the groupby to only consider the dates for id 684 between 2017-10-19 (i.e. one month later than the earliest date) and 2018-10-19 (i.e. one year after the earliest date plus one month).

I have tried straight groupby and Grouper to no avail.  None seem to have this ability to limit the consideration by date.  Perhaps I am missing something easy?  Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Will you please provide a sample expected output df?

Comment: It would be nice if you can show the expected groupby result.